# Image creating with PHP, only seems to accept png files

Tags: php, image, png, jpeg

SO I found this script, and I edited it. It's not quite finished, and stuff needs deleted from it, but What it does is creates a picture from html. I can't figure out how to make it accept other image types other than png. It just throws an error. I've tried everything I can think of, short of somewhat complex if statements that will probably just end up wrong as well. Any ideas on how to make this accept jpeg, png, and maybe even gifs?

```
$_GET['text']  = $row_recordset['Text'];
$_GET['text2']  = $row_recordset['Text2'];
$_GET['text3']  = $row_recordset['Text3'];
$_GET['text4']  = $row_recordset['Text4'];
$font_file     = $row_recordset['textFont'];
$image_file    = $row_recordset['Picture'];

$font_size = $row_recordset['textSize'];
$font_color = $row_recordset['textColor'];

if(empty($_GET['text']))    fatal_error('Error: You did not add any text. Hit the back button to finish it.') ;
$text = html_entity_decode($_GET['text']);
$text2 = html_entity_decode($_GET['text2']);
$text3 = html_entity_decode($_GET['text3']);
$text4 = html_entity_decode($_GET['text4']);
//$text = floatval($text);
//$text = number_format($text, 1, '.', '') . '%';

if(empty($text))
    fatal_error('Error: There was an error with the text font. Hit the back button and continue.') ;


$x_finalpos     = 775;
$y_finalpos     = 55;
$x_finalpos2     = 775;
$y_finalpos2     = 400;
$x_finalpos3     = 775;
$y_finalpos3     = 105;
$x_finalpos4     = 775;
$y_finalpos4     = 450;



$mime_type          = 'image/png' ;
$extension          = '.png' ;
$s_end_buffer_size  = 4096 ;


if(!function_exists('ImageCreate'))
    fatal_error('Error: Whoops, there was an error finishing up your e-card. Hit the back button and try again.') ;


if(!is_readable($font_file)) {
    fatal_error('Error: There was an error with the text font. Hit the back button and retry.') ;
}


$font_rgb = hex_to_rgb($font_color) ;
$box = @ImageTTFBBox($font_size,0,$font_file,$text) ;
$box2 = @ImageTTFBBox($font_size,0,$font_file,$text2) ;
$box3 = @ImageTTFBBox($font_size,0,$font_file,$text3) ;
$box4 = @ImageTTFBBox($font_size,0,$font_file,$text4) ;

$text_width = abs($box[2]-$box[0]);
$text_height = abs($box[5]-$box[3]);
$text_width2 = abs($box2[2]-$box2[0]);
$text_height2 = abs($box2[5]-$box2[3]);
$text_width3 = abs($box3[2]-$box3[0]);
$text_height3 = abs($box3[5]-$box3[3]);
$text_width4 = abs($box4[2]-$box4[0]);
$text_height4 = abs($box4[5]-$box4[3]);

$image =  imagecreatefrompng($image_file);
if(!$image || !$box)
{
    fatal_error('Error: There was an error with the text font. Hit the back button and retry.') ;
}


$font_color = ImageColorAllocate($image,$font_rgb['red'],$font_rgb['green'],$font_rgb['blue']) ;
$image_width = imagesx($image);
$put_text_x = $image_width - $text_width - ($image_width - $x_finalpos);
$put_text_y = $y_finalpos;

    $put_text_x2 = $image_width - $text_width2 - ($image_width - $x_finalpos2);
$put_text_y2 = $y_finalpos2;
$put_text_x3 = $image_width - $text_width3 - ($image_width - $x_finalpos3);
$put_text_y3 = $y_finalpos3;
$put_text_x4 = $image_width - $text_width4 - ($image_width - $x_finalpos4);
$put_text_y4 = $y_finalpos4;


imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $put_text_x,  $put_text_y, $font_color, $font_file, $text);
    imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $put_text_x2,  $put_text_y2, $font_color, $font_file, $text2);
    imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $put_text_x3,  $put_text_y3, $font_color, $font_file, $text3);
    imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $put_text_x4,  $put_text_y4, $font_color, $font_file, $text4);

header("Content-type: $mime_type");
ImagePNG($image) ;
ImageDestroy($image) ;
exit ;


function fatal_error($message)
{

    if(function_exists('ImageCreate'))
    {
        $width = ImageFontWidth(5) * strlen($message) + 10 ;
        $height = ImageFontHeight(5) + 10 ;
        if($image = ImageCreate($width,$height))
        {
            $background = ImageColorAllocate($image,255,255,255) ;
            $text_color = ImageColorAllocate($image,0,0,0) ;
            ImageString($image,5,5,5,$message,$text_color) ;    
            header('Content-type: image/png') ;
            ImagePNG($image) ;
            ImageDestroy($image) ;
            exit ;
        }
    }


    header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error") ;
    print($message) ;
    exit ;
}



function hex_to_rgb($hex) {
    // remove '#'
    if(substr($hex,0,1) == '#')
        $hex = substr($hex,1) ;


    if(strlen($hex) == 3) {
        $hex = substr($hex,0,1) . substr($hex,0,1) .
               substr($hex,1,1) . substr($hex,1,1) .
               substr($hex,2,1) . substr($hex,2,1) ;
    }

    if(strlen($hex) != 6)
        fatal_error('Error: Invalid color "'.$hex.'"') ;


    $rgb['red'] = hexdec(substr($hex,0,2)) ;
    $rgb['green'] = hexdec(substr($hex,2,2)) ;
    $rgb['blue'] = hexdec(substr($hex,4,2)) ;

    return $rgb ;
}
```

Comment: This line '$image =  imagecreatefrompng($image_file);' is probably key to finding a solution. The clue is in the function name. http://PHP.net/gd

Comment: I tried messing with that, as well as trying else if statements with imagetypes(). It doesn't seem to work though : /

Comment: Describing how it fails will help us to help you. What errors do you see?

Comment: A very vague error of The image "THE HTTP STUFF" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

It works with png files, but that's it.

Comment: Actually vascowhite, you are right! $image = imagecreatefrompng($image_file) will work with jpegs when changed to jpegs instead. However, I now need to figure out how to check the images extension from my database $row_recordset1['Picture'];

Comment: Did you read the [GD manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) I linked to?

Comment: Yes, I am looking at user comments at the moment.

Comment: I honestly can't figure out how to check the extension type. There are a lot of ways from what I can see, but Can;t get them working.

Comment: There is this code I found, but I'm not sure how to utilize this. 

    $type = @exif_imagetype($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

    if (($type >= 1) && ($type <= 3))
    {
        echo 'Valid image (GIF, JPG or PNG).';
    }

    else
    {
        unlink($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']); // delete it
    }

Comment: Apparently I don;t have exif installed even though I am using past php 5.0. I need to find another method in which to do this.

Comment: Can't you just check the filename? .png, .gif, .jpg etc..